# Airpush not sending right number of notifications & is there an alternative push notification network

Tags: android

I have installed airpush and i have set the settings 1 ad every 2 days,All Users,No ad delay. So i have over 100k net installs of my app. But airpush notification ads never cross 6k and they say fill rate is 98%. I have emailed them and tried other things by changing the days but nothing works the notification ad is only 6k everyday. Does anyone else had similar problem? Can they share solution.

Also next part of this question is there any good alternative to airpush? I have searched on google but did not find any other push notification ad network.

Comment: don't use AirPush!! they are a scam!! they never pay!! (to me and couple of buddies) or pay much less (google it!!)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try Leadboltapps. They offer Push Notifications, App Icon, App offer walls as well as regular ad formats. Once you integrate the SDK you just need to check the type of ads you want to show and the frequency.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm an Airpush representative. There could be two reasons for this issue:

1) Your ratio of current installs is much less than the 100k total installs  (due to uninstalls)

2) There's an issue with the SDK installation for your app. We are now working with the leading Android debugging company, and can provide you with our beta SDK which integrates their debugging. Please contact support for more information.

Hope that helps!

Airpush Support

Comment: I have contacted your support many times but no resolution yet. Also there is no way that 94k users uninstall the app. My app has about 1500 new install everyday. I think i will try the company mentioned above than getting paid pennies on my app.

Comment: AirPush is a scam!! you never pay!! (to me and couple of buddies) or pay much less (found on google!!)     ....You are THIEVES